# Hibernate criteria on embedded id member member value

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I would like to find an entity using a critera with restriction on the value of an attribute of a second entity wich is a member of the embedded id of my first entity.

First entity :

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id = new Id();

    private String color;

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8141132005371636607L;

        @ManyToOne
        private Owner owner;

        private String model;

        // getters and setters...
        // equals and hashcode methods

    }

    // getters and setters...

}
```

Second entity :

```
@Entity
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;    
    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "id.owner")
    private List<Car> cars;

    // getters and setters...

}
```

In this example, I would like to obtain the car with the color 'black', model 'batmobile' and the owner's firstname 'Bruce' (oops... spoiler ;) )

I tried to do something like that but it won't work :

```
List<Car> cars = session.createCriteria(Car.class)
      .add(Restrictions.eq("color", "black"))
      .add(Restrictions.eq("id.model", "batmobile"))
      .createAlias("id.owner", "o")
      .add(Restrictions.eq("o.firstname", "Bruce"))
      .list();
```

Result :

```
Hibernate: select this_.model as model1_0_0_, this_.owner_id as owner_id3_0_0_, this_.color as color2_0_0_ from Car this_ where this_.color=? and this_.model=? and o1_.firstname=?
ERROR: Unknown column 'o1_.firstname' in 'where clause'
```

What is the right way to obtain what I want ?

**update**

I tried in hql :

```
String hql = "FROM Car as car where car.color = :color and car.id.model = :model and car.id.owner.firstname = :firstname";

Query query = em.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("color", "black");
query.setParameter("model", "batmobile");
query.setParameter("firstname", "Bruce");

List<Car> cars = query.getResultList();
```

It works but is there a way to do this with criteria ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the alias and just using `.add(Restrictions.eq("id.owner.firstname", "Bruce"))`?

Comment: Actually, that's what I tried first. But it didn't work either. `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: id.owner.firstname of: my.package.domain.Car`

Comment: I have similar problem (Hibernate 3.3.2), could be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `@Column` annotation on top of the firstname and lastname fields (and the color field in Car). In hibernate if a field is not annotated, it doesn't recognize it as a database field. [This page should give you a good idea about how to set up your model objects](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm).

NOTE: You can have the column annotation over the getters and be fine, but you didn't show the getters. Either place is fine.

---

Look at what HQL is spitting back out, specifically the statement (formated for easier reading):

```
select 
    this_.model as model1_0_0_, 
    this_.owner_id as owner_id3_0_0_, 
    this_.color as color2_0_0_ 
from Car this_ 
where 
    this_.color=? 
    and this_.model=? 
    and o1_.firstname=?
```

It looks like hibernate is translating the field "id.owner" to "o" as your alias told it to to, but for some reason it's not writing down that "id.owner=o" as intended. You may want to do some research into why it may be doing that.

Comment: It's not an annotation problem. I don't know if it depends of the version of hibernate (or JPA) but @Column annonations are not obligatory.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4591 there is a workaround.

You have to copy the needed relation-property of the `@EmbeddedId` (`owner` in this case) to the main entity (`Car` in this case) with `insertable = false, updatable = false` as follows

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id = new Id();

    private String color;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "column_name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Owner owner;

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8141132005371636607L;

        @ManyToOne
        private Owner owner;

        private String model;

        // getters and setters...
        // equals and hashcode methods

    }

    // getters and setters...

}
```

Then just create directly the alias instead of using the composite id property

```
List<Car> cars = session.createCriteria(Car.class)
      .add(Restrictions.eq("color", "black"))
      .add(Restrictions.eq("id.model", "batmobile"))

      .createAlias("owner", "o")

      .add(Restrictions.eq("o.firstname", "Bruce"))
      .list();
```